# How to add a dropdownlist next to the filter box with Jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am using Jquery datatables (http://datatables.net/) for all grids on my asp.net pages. When the bFilter is enabled a search filter is displayed. I would like to add a dropdownlist (to select a specific column to apply filter) next to it? How do I add this html and also pass the dropdownlist value to my next page like "sSearch" uses:

```
<select>
  <option value="column1">column1/option>
  <option value="column2">column2</option>
  <option value="column3">column3</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of extending datatables with a function called `fnCreateFilterColumnSelector`. This function will add `<select>` elements next to all your search boxes, fill them with your available columns, and handle the `select.change` event to ensure the datatable only filters by that column.

This javascript code just needs to load after your datatables.js. Then, after initializing a `.dataTable();`, call the `fnCreateFilterColumnSelector` function.

## example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dt = $('table.display').dataTable();
    dt.fnCreateFilterColumnSelector();
});
```

## datatables extension code

```
(function ($, window, document) {
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnCreateFilterColumnSelector = function (oSettings) {
        var filterColumnSelectElement;
        $(oSettings.aanFeatures.f).each(function (index, filterDiv) {
            filterDiv = $(filterDiv);
            // see if we have a select here or not yet
            if (filterDiv.find(".dataTables_filterColumnSelect").length == 0) {
                // nope, so add one ... see if we have build the select yet
                if (filterColumnSelectElement === undefined) {
                    // the select hasn't been built yet, build it now
                    filterColumnSelectElement = $("<select></select>").addClass("dataTables_filterColumnSelect").css({ width: "120px", marginLeft: "10px" });
                    // add the all option
                    $("<option>*all</option>").val("all").appendTo(filterColumnSelectElement);
                    // add our bSearchable columns
                    $(oSettings.aoColumns).each(function (index, column) {
                        // see if this is a searchable column
                        if (column.bSearchable) {
                            // it is, add it (be sure to trim and remove \n chars
                            $("<option></option>").text(column.sTitle.replace(/\n/g, "").trim()).val(index).appendTo(filterColumnSelectElement);
                        }
                    });
                    // bind change event to select
                    filterColumnSelectElement.change(function () {
                        var theSelect = $(this);
                        // change all other elements to the same value
                        $(oSettings.aanFeatures.f).each(function (index, filterDiv) {
                            $(filterDiv).find(".dataTables_filterColumnSelect").val(theSelect.val());
                        });
                        // instead of overriding what the input does with our on code, we just just toggle the "bSearchable" values of our
                        // columns when we want to target an individual column ...
                        // see if we are going to search all
                        if (theSelect.val() === "all") {
                            // change all our columns back to searchable
                            $(theSelect.find("option")).each(function (i, theOption) {
                                // make sure the option has a number as a val
                                var columnIndex = parseInt($(theOption).val());
                                if (!isNaN(columnIndex)) {
                                    // switch it back to bSearchable
                                    oSettings.aoColumns[columnIndex].bSearchable = true;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            // change all the columns to not searchable
                            $(oSettings.aoColumns).each(function (i, column) {
                                column.bSearchable = false;
                            });
                            // change our selected colum to b searchable
                            oSettings.aoColumns[parseInt(theSelect.val())].bSearchable = true;
                        }
                        // kick off a search again ... need to clear out the last search to get it to do anything
                        oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch = "dummySearch";
                        $(theSelect).closest("div").find("input").trigger("keyup.DT");
                    });
                }
                // append a clone of our select element
                filterDiv.append(filterColumnSelectElement.clone(true));
                // increase the width of the div to fit the select
                filterDiv.css("width", (filterDiv.width() + filterColumnSelectElement.width() + 10).toString() + "px");
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly different, but let's put those filter options next to the column you'd filter on. Example taken from [datatable's site](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html). Go there for a live examle of how it ends up looking.

```
(function($) {
/*
 * Function: fnGetColumnData
 * Purpose:  Return an array of table values from a particular column.
 * Returns:  array string: 1d data array 
 * Inputs:   object:oSettings - dataTable settings object. This is always the last argument past to the function
 *           int:iColumn - the id of the column to extract the data from
 *           bool:bUnique - optional - if set to false duplicated values are not filtered out
 *           bool:bFiltered - optional - if set to false all the table data is used (not only the filtered)
 *           bool:bIgnoreEmpty - optional - if set to false empty values are not filtered from the result array
 * Author:   Benedikt Forchhammer <b.forchhammer /AT\ mind2.de>
 */
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetColumnData = function ( oSettings, iColumn, bUnique, bFiltered, bIgnoreEmpty ) {
    // check that we have a column id
    if ( typeof iColumn == "undefined" ) return new Array();

    // by default we only want unique data
    if ( typeof bUnique == "undefined" ) bUnique = true;

    // by default we do want to only look at filtered data
    if ( typeof bFiltered == "undefined" ) bFiltered = true;

    // by default we do not want to include empty values
    if ( typeof bIgnoreEmpty == "undefined" ) bIgnoreEmpty = true;

    // list of rows which we're going to loop through
    var aiRows;

    // use only filtered rows
    if (bFiltered == true) aiRows = oSettings.aiDisplay; 
    // use all rows
    else aiRows = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster; // all row numbers

    // set up data array    
    var asResultData = new Array();

    for (var i=0,c=aiRows.length; i<c; i++) {
        iRow = aiRows[i];
        var aData = this.fnGetData(iRow);
        var sValue = aData[iColumn];

        // ignore empty values?
        if (bIgnoreEmpty == true && sValue.length == 0) continue;

        // ignore unique values?
        else if (bUnique == true && jQuery.inArray(sValue, asResultData) > -1) continue;

        // else push the value onto the result data array
        else asResultData.push(sValue);
    }

    return asResultData;
}}(jQuery));


function fnCreateSelect( aData )
{
    var r='<select><option value=""></option>', i, iLen=aData.length;
    for ( i=0 ; i<iLen ; i++ )
    {
        r += '<option value="'+aData[i]+'">'+aData[i]+'</option>';
    }
    return r+'</select>';
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Initialise the DataTable */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        }
    } );

    /* Add a select menu for each TH element in the table footer */
    $("tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {
        this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
        $('select', this).change( function () {
            oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me this example!